# Placing Guest Order Programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, programmatically, guest-checkout

Hi I have a form posting information to a page which will then place an order as a guest with what is in the current sessions basket but I am having some issues.

I get the error:

> Please check shipping address information. Please enter the first
>   name. Please enter the last name. Please enter the street. Please
>   enter the city. Please enter the telephone number. Please enter the
>   zip/postal code. Please enter the country.

I have done a var_dump of the shipping and billing addresses and they look fine my POST is passing the info correctly. Can anyone spot what might be wrong?

```
  $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
  $checkout->initCheckout();


  $checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('guest');


  $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
  $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
  $emailaddress = $_POST["email"];
  $confirmemailaddress = $_POST["cemail"];

  if(isset($_POST['tel'])):
    $telephone = $_POST['tel'];
  else:
    $telephone = "Not Applicable";
  endif;

  if(isset($_POST['postcode'])):
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
  else:
    $postcode = "Not Applicable";
  endif;

  if(isset($_POST['addr1'])):
    $street1 = $_POST['addr1'];
  else:
    $street1 = "Not Applicable";
  endif;

  if(isset($_POST['addr2'])):
    $street2 = $_POST['addr2'];
  else:
    $street2 = "Not Applicable";
  endif;

  if(isset($_POST['city'])):
    $city = $_POST['city'];
  else:
    $city = "Not Applicable";
  endif;

  $billingAddress =  array (
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $emailaddress,
    'street' => Array(
        '0' => $street1,
        '1' => $street2
    ),
    'city' => $city,
    'postcode' => $postcode,
    'country_id' => 'GB',
    'telephone' => $telephone,
  );

  $shippingAddress =  array (
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $emailaddress,
    'street' => Array(
        '0' => $street1,
        '1' => $street2
    ),
    'city' => $city,
    'postcode' => $postcode,
    'country_id' => 'GB',
    'telephone' => $telephone,
  );

  $checkout->saveBilling($billingAddress, true);

  $checkout->saveShipping($shippingAddress, true);

  $checkout->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

  $checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'free'));

  $checkout->saveOrder();

  foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
   Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, Its tested and working.

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();


$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('guest');


$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$emailaddress = $_POST["email"];
$confirmemailaddress = $_POST["cemail"];

if(isset($_POST['tel'])):
$telephone = $_POST['tel'];
else:
$telephone = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['postcode'])):
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
else:
$postcode = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['addr1'])):
$street1 = $_POST['addr1'];
else:
$street1 = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['addr2'])):
$street2 = $_POST['addr2'];
else:
$street2 = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['city'])):
$city = $_POST['city'];
else:
$city = "Not Applicable";
endif;

$billingAddress =  array (
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'email' => $emailaddress,
'street' => Array(
    '0' => $street1,
    '1' => $street2
),
'city' => $city,
'postcode' => $postcode,
'country_id' => 'GB',
'telephone' => $telephone,
);

$shippingAddress =  array (
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'email' => $emailaddress,
'street' => Array(
    '0' => $street1,
    '1' => $street2
),
'city' => $city,
'postcode' => $postcode,
'country_id' => 'GB',
'telephone' => $telephone,
);

$checkout->saveBilling($billingAddress,null);

$checkout->saveShipping($shippingAddress,null);

$checkout->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->collectTotals();

$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'free'));

$checkout->saveOrder();

foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveBilling()

Comment: This workd if I turn off developer mode and error reporting which I can't really do, any ideas on how to get this working cleanly?

Comment: Updated code. For shipping method error Make sure you have free shipping method enabled

Comment: Yes I have free shipping enabled, with dev off and reporting off it goes in as an order and sets the correct shipping but why?

Comment: Let me try with developer mode on

Comment: With above code and with developer mode enabled + reporting on, I am able to place order. Can you try with updated code please. I am using Magento ver 1.9.3.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56315/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-kiwistastegood).

Comment: It worked :) Thanks! What is the difference between the true and null?